# What's the common way to access a MongoDB with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, nginx, mongoose

Let's say I wrote a little `HTML` site, deployed on my `nginx` webserver. I created a database with `MongoDB` and stored several million entries in it. The `MongoDB` server is only listening on the local interface and accessible via localhost:27017.

Now I want to go to my webpage on my publicly accessible `nginx` webserver and access the entries in the database via `JavaScript`, by clicking a button "Show Users" or "Get latest entries" and so on. I need to perform only simple read-only-queries on the database like counting, searching, aggregating, and so on, so I don't need write access.

How do you generally implement this? Do I really need to set up `PHP`, `Python`, and `Java` to access the DB or is it somehow possible to solve this by only using `HTTP`/`REST` Interfaces? Can `NodeJS` help me to solve this? Do I have to remove `nginx` when using `NodeJS`?

Sorry, but I'm quite confused with all that `JavaScript`/ `NodeJS`/ `mongoose`/ `MongoDB`/ `JSON` stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep nginx as server for static content like your html files. To serve dynamic data, use node.js to create a rest interface. The rest interface will provide the data it fetches from your MongoDb.

Since you have millions of entries in your database and do not require complex functionality I would recommend the [mongodb-native-driver](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native) as node.js module.

On the client, use ajax to perform api calls to your created rest interface.

Mongoose is built on top of the native driver to allow object modeling.

Comment: Ok, just to make it clear. My websites are stored on my nginx server which is accessible via the internet. My MongoDB database is still listening on 127.0.0.1:27017. My NodeJS rest interface is accessible via the internet. My HTML sites are requesting entries from the database via AJAX calls to the NodeJS REST Interface. Correct?

Comment: Yes, but you should make sure that your node.js application is able to access the mongod instance since its only available via localhost.